# Create Table in iOS

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone, web

I want to make table in HTML and embded in objective c and after load in HTML . I am using this code i am not getting table.

```
myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

NSString *embedHtml=@"<html><head><title>First</title><style>table , td, table , tr, th{border:1px solid #333333;padding:2px;}</style></head><body><table ><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th><th>Col5</th></tr>";

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    thiss= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<tr><td>Data1</td><td> %@</td><td>Data1</td><td>Data1</td><td>Data1</td></tr>",[array objectAtIndex:i]];

    [myArray addObject:thiss];



}
thiss =[embedHtml stringByAppendingString:[myArray objectAtIndex:0]];

NSString *idd=[thiss stringByAppendingString:@"</table></body></html>"];

NSLog(@"%@",idd);

  [webview loadHTMLString:idd baseURL:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",thiss);
```

Comment: What is your exact problem here? Trying out your code (and adding the missing types) prints out your html. Can you confirm that your webView is visible on screen?

Comment: ya webview is visible on screen but they shown only first row i want three row it is due to  [myArray objectAtIndex:0] how we get all three

Comment: You can simplify the code by using array literals: `array=@[@"1",@"2",@"3"];` and instead of `[array objectAtIndex:i]` just `array[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from your comment the only problem you have, is that only the first row is shown. That is because you only add the first row to the html outside of the for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    thiss= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<tr><td>Data1</td><td> %@</td><td>Data1</td><td>Data1</td><td>Data1</td></tr>",[array objectAtIndex:i]];

    [myArray addObject:thiss];
}

thiss =[embedHtml stringByAppendingString:[myArray objectAtIndex:0]];
```

not sure for what you use the array. but adding the html directly to the string inside the for loop solves your problem: (cleaned code)

```
// creating values with shorter literal syntax
NSArray *values = @[@"1",@"2",@"3"];

// create mutable string
NSMutableString *embedHTML = [@"<html><head><title>First</title><style>table , td, table , tr, th{border:1px solid #333333;padding:2px;}</style></head><body><table ><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th><th>Col5</th></tr>" mutableCopy];

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    // create row html and append it to mutable embedHTML
    NSString *rowHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<tr><td>Data1</td><td> %@</td><td>Data1</td><td>Data1</td><td>Data1</td></tr>", values[i]];
    [embedHTML appendString:rowHTML];
}

// finish html
[embedHTML appendString:@"</table></body></html>"];

NSLog(@"%@", embedHTML);
[webview loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Also note, that if you have a fixed width values array, using for in loop is much simpler, understandable and maintainable than using for:

```
for (NSString *value in values) {
    // create row html and append it to mutable embedHTML
    NSString *rowHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<tr><td>Data1</td><td> %@</td><td>Data1</td><td>Data1</td><td>Data1</td></tr>", value];
    [embedHTML appendString:rowHTML];
}
```

therefore there is no redundancy and as soon as you extend the values array your code keeps working as expected.